# Аналог OpenDialog на Android

Tags: android, delphi

Существует ли "простой" способ передавать путь файла в MediaPlayer для воспроизведения видео на Delphi в Multi-Device platform, а конкретно на android? Перепробовал уже много разных вариантов и с стэковерфлоу и с китайского форума -- ничего не работает. Прошу, наведите, пожалуйста, на библиотеки, которые надо изучить в Delphi и хотя бы примерный алгоритм работы программы "исследователя" файла.

Я пробовал компонент ActionList и действие TakePhotoFromLibraryAction и привязывал его кнопке, но он передаёт только фото, видео этот компонент передавать не может. Для изображения файла я использова Image. В delphi для отображения видео есть два компонента: MediaPlayer && MediaPlayerControl. Первый принимает по свойству FileName адрес файла, а второй отображает этот файл. К сожалению, в Multi-Device Platform в Rad Studio разработка под Android не предусмотрен выбор файлов из галереи, то есть нет аналога OpenDialog(windows). Поискав в интернете я наткнулся на китаский форум, где один разработчик создал File Explorer, который выбирает файлы из галереи, а после в Edit передаёт адресс этого файла:
https://bluexmas.tistory.com/427
На stackoverlow уже были подобные вопросы, я переписал код, попытался запустить, но там всего лишь выдавался адрес папки приложения, заходить в галерею и выбирать файлы, а после получать их адресс мне не удалось.

Comment: Вы пробовали стандартный для Android/iOS выбор файлов из Галереи, он вас не устраивает? Уточните чем, в вопросе (кнпка "править")

Comment: Сторонним приложениям нечего "исследовать" файлы пользователя. Это одна из последний тенденций в системе безопасности Андроид. Вам нужно смотреть в сторону MediaStore API, забудьте про файловую систему.

Comment: @Kromster Я дополнил вопрос. Стандартный для Android / IOS выбор файлов из Галереи -- это IOUtils? Нет, не пробовал. То есть надо изучить этот юнит?